# how to fetch value from a session code which is created using a randomNumber variable which is not shown in response data

Tags: jmeter

i am trying to add a document in a program in which there are unique session ID generated in each session. So when i write the code in jemeter it works perfectly and after the session time is over it wont work. when i try to write a regular expression its also not working becuase the session ID is created using a random variable from the code. And the random variable is not shown anywhere in the server response. hence regular expressions are failing.

```
$('#hdUniqueSessionKey').val(randomNumber + "_" + $('#ddlWorkFlowTeam').val());
```

here the randomNumber henerated is not available anywhere in the server response or body. so how can i get the value which is inside the randomNumber in Jmeter

```
$('#hdUniqueSessionKey').val(**randomNumber** + "_" + $('#ddlWorkFlowTeam').val());
```

I need to get the Unique session ID and i tried using regular expressions. but in regular expression

```
[$][(]'#hdUniqueSessionKey'[)][.]val[(](.*)[)];
```

it just fetches the string for me. and not the value inside it. I need to get the value inside the Randomnumber variable. can anyone help me in getting that.

---

> how can i extract the values of **randomNumber** and **ddlWorkFlowTeam**

---

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMeter's [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) in order to generate a random number in the given range like:

```
${__Random(1,100,randomNumber)}
```

`ddlWorkFlowTeam` looks like something which can be extracted. So you can obtain the sum of the `ddlWorkFlowTeam` and the random number using [__longsum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum)

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction/)

Comment: That randomNumber is a result of some function and its generated by the website. It doesent have any relation with the random number of Jmeter. luke you said the value of ddlWorkFlowTeam can be extracted. thats the way i needed. becuase i need to extract this randomNumber as well in the same way.

Comment: In that case you can implement the same function using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) language

Comment: can you tell me how it can be done to implement this to get the value of the hdUniqueSessionKey

Comment: I am not enough telepathic in order to guess what exact code is being used to generate this session key in your application

Comment: document.getElementById("id_globalTabSessionKey").value = (getRandomNumber())                                                                                      var randomNumber = getRandomNumber();
                      
$('#hdUniqueSessionKey').val(randomNumber + "_" + $('#ddlWorkFlowTeam').val());     the ddlworkflowteam is balnk in most cases. what i want is the random number along with an underscore